# Azure - Need futher explanation regarding edge case

Tags: azure

I think something is up with my billing... while MS don't answer i thought about posting my suposed issue here.

My question is "I added an instance to my role at 1:10 and deleted it at 1:20. I will be billed 1 hour. If I start another instance at 1:30 and stop it at 1:40 i will be billed for another hour?"

You might think that this wont influence the bill so much, but due to a misconfigured auto-scale i think that the scenario above might have happened about 50 times in the last thirty days...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that's exactly what you'll see. You're being billed for a minimum of one clock-hour for each of those instances. Note: I believe there's a 5-minute "grace" window, but it looks like you're going beyond that.

Having said that: If it's happened about 50 times, you're seeing at most 50 compute-hours beyond where you expected to be, right? If that's the case, at least you caught it early, when it's only cost you about $5.00 (assuming Small instance with single core).

Comment: +1 would you have any documentation supporting your answer? (just asking...)

Comment: David is correct: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-2

Quote: "Partial Cloud Services instance hours are billed as full Cloud Services hours for each clock hour an instance is deployed. For example, if you deploy a small Cloud Services instance at 10:50 AM and delete the deployment at 11:10 AM, you will be billed for two small Cloud Services hours, one hour for usage during 10:50 AM to 11:00 AM and another hour for usage during 11 AM to 11:10 AM."